# How do I edit a word in a Word TOC to be different from how it appears on the chapter page?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

I have created an automatic TOC in Word 2013. My chapter titles are styled to fit the design of the opening page of the chapter ("one", all lower case, written out). In the TOC itself, I would like it to say "Chapter 1", (to distinguish it from preface, glossary, etc.), plus a small part of the sub-title. But it won't happily edit the TOC to be different from the chapter page (it will let me do it, but randomly just reverts). Is there an effective way to edit a generated TOC?

Comment: Never mind, I've managed a work-around.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please consider writing up your work-around as a [self-answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). That way, it will help others who might have the same question.